# How can I keep ExtJS 4.1.1 from messing up the Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1 layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, conflict, extjs4.1

I really don't like ExtJS but I'm forced to use it.  I want to use Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1 for the main layout and ExtJS for grids and JS (policy).

I have an awesome looking Bootstrap design going but the minute I load ExtJS, the navbar, fonts, etc get all hosed up.

Is there a way I can get the two to work together without going into the ExtJS and tweaking tons of CSS?

The CSS file I am using is in the following path (for ExtJS):

```
js/extjs/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried loading bootstrap css last?

Comment: try [extjs-theme-bootstrap](https://github.com/NewbridgeGreen/extjs-theme-bootstrap) - Twitter Bootstrap Theme for ExtJS 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:
1.use ext-all-scoped.css instead of ext-all.css
2.add the following code before you load ext-all.js

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Ext = {
    buildSettings:{
        "scopeResetCSS": true
    }
};
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxx.com/extjs/ext-all.js'></script>
```

3.remove the following declaration in ext-all-scoped.css to prevent extjs to re-render the body with those conflict css declarations after bootstrap has been loaded

```
.x-body {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the rule

```
.x-border-box .x-reset,.x-border-box .x-reset * {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

is somehow being applied for all page elements, also for Twitter Bootstrap input's (tested on FF, Chrome).
So you should simply provide

```
box-sizing:content-box !important;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box !important; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box !important; /* Safari */
```

for all Twitter input's.
Additional info on [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

I hope that this helps.